# Dspace in AIP export: (The system can not find the path specified)

Tags: java, dspace

I'am trying personal export my repository via AIP, but I'm getting the following error. I verified and actually file in assestored folder does not exist. Is there a way to export the repository ignoring these items deleted by Dspace ?

I am getting the following error:

```
C:\dspace\bin>dspace packager -d -a -t AIP -e brendow007@gmail.com -i capes/0 sitewide-aip.zip
Using DSpace installation in: C:\dspace

Disseminating DSpace SITE [ hdl=capes/0 ] to sitewide-aip.zip

Also disseminating all child objects (recursive mode)..
This may take a while, please check your logs for ongoing status while we process each package.
Exception: C:\dspace\assetstore\40\91\65\40916552143129972874895263919005470063 (O sistema n├úo conseguiu localizar o caminho especificado)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\dspace\assetstore\40\91\65\40916552143129972874895263919005470063 (O sistema n├úo conseguiu localizar o caminho especificado)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
        at edu.sdsc.grid.io.local.LocalFileInputStream.open(LocalFileInputStream.java:171)
        at edu.sdsc.grid.io.GeneralFileInputStream.(GeneralFileInputStream.java:145)
        at edu.sdsc.grid.io.local.LocalFileInputStream.(LocalFileInputStream.java:139)
        at edu.sdsc.grid.io.FileFactory.newFileInputStream(FileFactory.java:630)
        at org.dspace.storage.bitstore.BitstreamStorageManager.retrieve(BitstreamStorageManager.java:525)
        at org.dspace.content.Bitstream.retrieve(Bitstream.java:593)
        at org.dspace.content.crosswalk.LicenseStreamDisseminationCrosswalk.disseminate(LicenseStreamDisseminationCrosswalk.java:60)
        at org.dspace.content.packager.AbstractMETSDisseminator.makeMdSec(AbstractMETSDisseminator.java:660)
        at org.dspace.content.packager.AbstractMETSDisseminator.addToAmdSec(AbstractMETSDisseminator.java:736)
        at org.dspace.content.packager.AbstractMETSDisseminator.addAmdSec(AbstractMETSDisseminator.java:763)
        at org.dspace.content.packager.AbstractMETSDisseminator.makeManifest(AbstractMETSDisseminator.java:848)
        at org.dspace.content.packager.AbstractMETSDisseminator.writeZipPackage(AbstractMETSDisseminator.java:320)
        at org.dspace.content.packager.AbstractMETSDisseminator.disseminate(AbstractMETSDisseminator.java:259)
        at org.dspace.content.packager.DSpaceAIPDisseminator.disseminate(DSpaceAIPDisseminator.java:160)
        at org.dspace.content.packager.AbstractPackageDisseminator.disseminateAll(AbstractPackageDisseminator.java:103)
        at org.dspace.content.packager.AbstractPackageDisseminator.disseminateAll(AbstractPackageDisseminator.java:138)
        at org.dspace.content.packager.AbstractPackageDisseminator.disseminateAll(AbstractPackageDisseminator.java:159)
        at org.dspace.content.packager.AbstractPackageDisseminator.disseminateAll(AbstractPackageDisseminator.java:170)
        at org.dspace.app.packager.Packager.disseminate(Packager.java:641)
        at org.dspace.app.packager.Packager.main(Packager.java:460)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.dspace.app.launcher.ScriptLauncher.runOneCommand(ScriptLauncher.java:226)
        at org.dspace.app.launcher.ScriptLauncher.main(ScriptLauncher.java:78)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of things you could try.

1. Delete the bitstream that is causing the error (Go to edit item, bitstreams, delete)
2. Try exporting each top level community

If that missing item is an isolated issue, you should be able to fix the data.  If it is not isolated, it will be more difficult to run a single export.

It is also possible to specify specific bundles that you would like to export.  If your missing data is isolated to a specific bundle (LICENSE, TEXT), you might also be able to work around the issue that way.

```
packager -d -e ${USER} -t AIP -o includeBundles=ORIGINAL,LICENSE -i ...
```

https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/AIP+Backup+and+Restore#AIPBackupandRestore-AdditionalPackagerOptions

Looking at that documentation, there is an option "skipIfParentMissing" that might be worth trying.